# How to run a explain query when a binary field is in the where clause

Tags: mysql

I need to check the query plan for the following query on MySQL using EXPLAIN.

But the problem is the column in the where clause is binary(16). Its a guid.

```
explain select `title`,`ttext` 
FROM ptip inner join user on user.id = ptip.userId
where ptip.titlehash = <whatever value>
```

Here the titlehash is binary(16) and the query gives the following error:

'Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables'

I tried using; where ptip.titlehash = BINARY('24dwdfsdf') but still the same;

How do you run the above query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here's how I finally solved it;

```
SET @hs = (SELECT titlehash FROM ptip WHERE id = 5673);
EXPLAIN SELECT `title`,`ttext` 
FROM ptip INNER JOIN USER ON user.id = ptip.userId
WHERE ptip.titlehash  = @hs
```

I put the value in the @hs variable and then use for explain. Fortunately the explain command explains the select only. It doesn't care about the SET operation and treat the @hs variable as just a value

Answer (score 0):

> Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables

**What does this mean:**
`Const tables` means MySQL has noticed that only one row can match on the join. Instead if reading this inside the query it stores this row in a `const table`

According to the MySQL manual:

> The table has at most one matching row, which is read at the start of the query. Because there is only one row, values from the column in this row can be regarded as constants by the rest of the optimizer. const tables are very fast because they are read only once.

**The problem**
The problem that **you** are having here is that MySQL has noticed that there are no matching rows in your join. For that reason MySQL cannot read a row into the const table and cannot start the query.

**The solution**
Fix the query do it does not return an empty resultset and run explain again.

Comment: Yes; the problem is putting the value in the where clause. The column used in the where clause (titlehash) is BINARY(16) it actually contains a GUID. When I run a select on that it shows the data as blob but nothing else. So how do I put the value in the where clause ? In sql server it shows guids in the xxxx-xxx-xxx.. format but in this mysql it does not show the actual characters